# What's the best way to create flink table for time series data

Tags: python, apache-flink, pyflink

I have aws kinesis data format as follows:

```
[
    {
        'customer_id': UUID,
        'sensor_id': UUID,
        'timestamps': [ ... ],
        'values': [ ...]
    },
    ...
]
```

I later want to apply a Sliding Window on the data based on event time (which is included in time stamps.

What's the best way to model the Flink table given that the data scheme contains arrays?

Comment: If the timestamp and values array are of same size, you can apply a FlatMapFunction on the stream and expand each row into multiple rows for each timestamps and value entry.

Comment: Yes, timestamps and values are of the same length, could you share a snippet?

Answer (score 0):

Every record from Kinesis would get a timestamp provided by Kinesis. However, you want to use a custom timestamp that is embedded in the record. Also, each Kinesis record has multiple timestamps and all of them should be considered timestamps.

You can do this in two steps (note that I have not tested this out. it is a high level code):

Step 1: Apply the [flatmap transformation](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.16/docs/dev/datastream/operators/overview/#flatmap) to each input record and transform them to multiple records with unique timestamps and values into a datastream.

```
def expand_element(record):
    #convert embedded timesptamp records to individual records


flat_map_stream = kinesis_stream.flatmap(expand_element)
```

After the flat_map transformation your records will just have one timestamp and value each (note the new column `timestamp` and `value`):

```
[
    {
        'customer_id': UUID,
        'sensor_id': UUID,
        'timestamp': long,
        'value': str
    },
    ...
]
```

Step 2: On this flat mapped stream [generate your custom watermark](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.16/docs/dev/datastream/event-time/generating_watermarks/) on the `timestamp` field.

```
#Define the custom TimestampAssigner and WatermarkStrategy. 
class FirstElementTimestampAssigner(TimestampAssigner):
    def extract_timestamp(self, value, record_timestamp):
        return value['timestamp'] #This is new the timestamp column


watermark_strategy = WatermarkStrategy 
    .for_bounded_out_of_orderness(Duration.of_seconds(20)) 
    .with_timestamp_assigner(FirstElementTimestampAssigner())

#Assign the watermark strategy to the new stream.
flat_map_stream_with_watermark = flat_map_stream.    .assign_timestamp_and_watermarks(watermark_strategy)
```

Now you can apply window functions on the stream `flat_map_stream_with_watermark` to use your custom `timestamp` field as event time.